# Is it possible to upgrade nokia lumia 510 to windows phone8

Tags: windows-phone

I have nokialumia510, 
is it possible to upgrade it to wp8, so that i need to test my app which i have developed in wp8 sdk.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to upgrade any Windows Phone to Windows Phone 8. Your Lumia 510 only can be upgraded to Windows Phone 7.8.

WP8 is a new platform not related with old Windows Phone 7. If you want to test your app you must buy a new devide with WP8 installed.